# some integral inequality

Tags: calculus

I need help to prove the following integral inequality.
$f$ is a continuous function in $[-1,1]$.

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}f^{2}(x)dx \geq \frac{1}{2}\left(\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx\right)^2 + \frac{3}{2}\left(\int_{-1}^{1}xf(x)dx\right)^2
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $M = \frac12 \int_{-1}^{1} f(x) \mathrm{d}x$. Let $g(x) = f(x) - M$. We have

1. $\int_{-1}^{1} \lambda g  = 0$ for any constant $\lambda$, so
2. $\int_{-1}^{1} f^2 = \int (g + M)^2 = \int g^2 + M^2 = \int_{-1}^{1} g^2 + \frac12 (\int_{-1}^1 f)^2$
3. Next, $\int_{-1}^1 xM = 0$.
4. So it suffices to show $\int_{-1}^1 g^2 \geq \frac32 (\int_{-1}^1 xg)^2$

This last line follows from Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Did you use fact that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Only in that the integrals are well-defined. The statement is true for any measurable function $f$ on $[-1.1]$ whose square is Lebesgue integrable, so continuity is sufficient but not necessary.

Comment: I also used Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for integrals on right side. But I didn't notice this equality $\int[f(x)-M]dx=0$. Very beautiful solution!.